# Syntax Error when running Falcon Framework tutorial with gunicorn

Tags: python, falconframework

Here is the stack trace: https://gist.github.com/guyjacks/a8e7cda23ed87a6900fd

Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/guyjacks/3b3ca07fa62bd679cca3

Installed packages: https://gist.github.com/guyjacks/8e582fcf5d19547dd729

Python version: 3.2.5 on Mac OSX.

Virtualenv is activated so its not that!

FYI, it works fine when using cpython 3.4.3.

Answer (score 1):

The error message:

```
DEFAULT_ERROR_LOG_FORMAT = (u'{0:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S} [FALCON] [ERROR]'
                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

is pretty clear here. Python cannot make sense of the string.

The `u''` syntax for strings is only supported for Python 2 and Python >= 3.3. Python 3.2 is really old. You need to upgrade your Python version. If possible, I would recommend to switch to Python 3.5 right away.

Comment: @guyja You can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it answers your question

Comment: I am using 3.5 already, but Falcon's biggest strength is that its supposed to run on PyPy which can only interpret Python code up to version 3.2.5.